# Modify an array with values from mysql table in php

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I've this json call that is working fine: (just look at the $categorias array)

```
$query_tienda = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tiendas");
$resultado_tienda = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_tienda);
$nombre_tienda= $resultado_tienda['nombre'];

$action = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])&& $_REQUEST['action'] !=NULL)?$_REQUEST['action']:'';
if($action == 'ajax'){
include("conexion_all.php");//Contiene los datos de conexion a la base de datos
$periodo=intval($_REQUEST['periodo']);
$txt_mes=array( "1"=>"Ene","2"=>"Feb","3"=>"Mar","4"=>"Abr","5"=>"May","6"=>"Jun",
                "7"=>"Jul", "8"=>"Ago","9"=>"Sep","10"=>"Oct","11"=>"Nov",  "12"=>"Dic"
             );//Arreglo que contiene las abreviaturas de los meses del año
```

---

```
$categorias []= array('Mes','Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4');
```

---

```
for ($inicio = 1; $inicio <= 12; $inicio++) {
    $mes=$txt_mes[$inicio];//Obtengo la abreviatura del mes
    $tienda_1=monto('1',$inicio,$periodo);//Obtengo ingresos de la tienda
    $tienda_2=monto('2',$inicio,$periodo);
    $tienda_3=monto('3',$inicio,$periodo);
    $tienda_4=monto('4',$inicio,$periodo);
    $categorias []= array($mes,$tienda_1,$tienda_2,$tienda_3,$tienda_4);//Agrego elementos al arreglo


}
echo json_encode( ($categorias) );//Convierto el arreglo a formato json
}
```

And need to change that part with something like this:

```
$categorias = array('Mes');      
while ($contador = mysqli_fetch_array($query_tienda)) {
    $categorias [] = $contador['name'];
}
```

To achieve the same result. I've trie diferent ways with no result, like:

```
$categorias = array('Mes'); 
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($query_tienda) {
    $row = array();
    $row = array($r['nombre']);
    array_push($categorias,$row);
    unset($row);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

UPDATED: Finally find a solution:

```
$query_tienda = $mysqli->query("SELECT nombre FROM tiendas");        
$cat = "Mes";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_tienda)){
    $cat .= ','.$row['nombre'];
    $row++;
}

$categorias []= explode(',', $cat);
```

Thanks for all!!!

Comment: first, you need sure $r have data
then, $r['nombre'] isset ?
btw, why duplicate declare $row ? and unset($row) ?

Comment: In `PHP` add this `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` to display errors and post what it'll show you. Also, you are missing a `)` before the `{` at `while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($query_tienda) {`

Comment: I've put the missing ), and the ini_set... where are the error displayed? I'm using firefox, with F12 I can see console and have this one: Error: Row 3 has 5 columns, but must have 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated and solved.

```
$query_tienda = $mysqli->query("SELECT nombre FROM tiendas");        
$cat = "Mes";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_tienda)){
    $cat .= ','.$row['nombre'];
    $row++;
}

$categorias []= explode(',', $cat);
```